# Proving the independence of the given statistics

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, independence

Let $(X_1, Y_1), ..., (X_n, Y_n)   (n>2)$ be random samples from the bivariate normal distribution $N_2 (\mu_1, \mu_2; \sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2, \rho)$, where $\sigma_1>0, \sigma_2>0, -1<\rho<1$.

Let $r$ be the sample correlation coefficient defined as $r= \frac{\sum_1^n (X_i - \bar X )(Y_i - \bar Y)}{\sqrt{\sum_1^n (X_i-\bar X)^2}\sqrt{\sum_1^n (Y_i -\bar Y)^2}}$ where $\bar X, \bar Y$ are sample means of $X_i$'s and $Y_i$'s, respectively.

Also, let $Z_i = (X_i-\mu_1)/\sigma_1$, $W_i=\{(Y_i-\mu_2)/\sigma_2-\rho(X_i-\mu_1)/\sigma_1\}/\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$ for $i=1, ..., n$.

Now prove the followings:

(a) $S_{WW}-S_{ZW}^2/S_{ZZ} $ and $Z=(Z_1, ..., Z_n)$ are independent.

(b) $S_{ZW}/\sqrt{S_{ZZ}} $ and $Z$ are independent.

(c) $S_{WW}-S_{ZW}^2/S_{ZZ}, S_{ZW}/\sqrt{S_{ZZ}}, S_{ZZ}$ are indenepdent.

Where $S_{ZZ} = \sum_1^n (Z_i-\bar Z)^2$, $S_{WW} = \sum_1^n (W_i-\bar W)^2$, $S_{ZW} = \sum_1^n (Z_i-\bar Z)(W_i-\bar W)$.

What I know is that if $T=((Z_1-\bar Z)/\sqrt{S_{ZZ}}, ..., (Z_n-\bar Z)/\sqrt{S_{ZZ}}$), then $S_{WW}-S_{ZW}^2/S_{ZZ}=W^t(I-n^{-1} 11^t-TT^t)W$, where $1$ is the vector where all entries are 1.

Also, it is known that $Z=(Z_1, ..., Z_n)$ and $W=(W_1, ..., W_n)$ are independent.

How should I prove the independence this case? Using pdf or mgf to prove independence here seems ridiculous.

Comment: I have a hunch that using the theory developed around normal sampling theory could help. If you analyze the the mean and variance of the $Z_{i}$ and $W_{i}$, you might be able to figure out the distributions of the $S_{ZZ}^{2}, S_{WW}^{2}$ and $S_{ZW}^{2}$ in terms of chi-squared distributions.  From there you might be able to work our the distributions of your various quantities. From there the known properties of these distributions might help although I think that some of them will not be nice. Oh, also, it might be useful to know in what context this question appears.